# Excel Maco: How to use a variable filename

Tags: excel, filenames, vba

I created a macro, but it has inserted the filename from the file I was in when I created it.  I want to use it for many files with many different names (potentially thousands of files).  How do I make the macro independent of the filename?  below the filename "ADP" is used and now this macro won't work with other filenames e.g. "CPL" or "DKH"

```
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ADP").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ADP").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ADP").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G7694")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data\ADP.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your macro in a Sub procedure with parameters and make a second sub that calls it, like so

```
Sub MyMacro(file as string, worksheetname as string)
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetname).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetname).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetname).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G7694")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Sub Usage()
  MyMacro "C:\Data\ADP.csv", "ADP"
  MyMacro "C:\Data\CPL.csv", "CPL"
End Sub
```